# The CSV file format that I'm using is strange and cannot be used

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My CSV file is in the following format.

```
"AUS"   "market"
"DEFAULT_LATITUDE"  "-13614588"
"DEFAULT_LONGITUDE" "52188316"
```

There is an unspecified number of spaces between each field(I guess, \t), and it is enclosed in double quotation marks.
When I open my CSV file using Excel, it fits into each cell well.
However, I'd like to read the data into Python. (using panda or csv module)
Which option should I use?

Here is my code and output.

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pd.read_csv("export.csv", delimiter='\t')
    print(data)
```

[image]

Comment: If it's tab separated it's TSV

Comment: Can you check if space between two words is constant or not? Looks like it's not tab separated.

Comment: @Amit Vikram Singh  
When I open the csv file with the notepad program that I was using  
I noticed that the tap character had a different spacing. Actually it's a tap.

Comment: Okay. So you are able to get the desired output?

Comment: I've solved it, When I used the tap character from my notepad by Ctrl+C/V, I was able to read normally.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.
When I used the tap character from my notepad by Ctrl+C/V, I was able to read  normally.

[image]